Modelica Variable Clock at solver's time steps
I need to make an event to force the solver to stop at each time step that it takes to run an algorithm.
Making events (discontinuity) can be done using a clock but the clock is periodic. For example, it makes an event every 100 ms which forces the solver to reduce the time step to meet the events at each 100 ms. I was wondering if there is a way to devise a clock that acts in a variable way. If so, how can I make it act at each solver time step without meddeling the time steps taken by the solver. In other words, I want the solver operate normally and take variable time steps but an event also be imposed at each time step providing the opportunity for running an algorithm.

The only way to do this is to change the way the runtime code interacts with the solver. Basically write a Modelica external function that queries the solver step.

What do you want the event for? This sounds like an X-Y problem; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

I don't actually understand the question. Why would you want to trigger an event when the solver takes a step anyways? I have seen the (mis-)usage of events to avoid too big solver steps, but that doesn't seem to be your target. Also, you can define variable time-steps for a clocked signal e.g. using Modelica.Clocked.ClockSignals.Clocks.EventClock.
